What are the attributes for the showAttribute() method of the AdminConfig object?
I would like to know what are the attributes for the showAttribute() method of the AdminConfig object ?
The AdminConfig object is used to invoke configuration commands and to create, read, update and delete (CRUD) elements of the WebSphere® Application Server configuration.
I would like to query an attribute related with Application Login and Login Module configurations, but I don't know if such an attribute exists and can be inpputed in the showAttribute method :

I believe that I could use the attributes command to return a list of top-level attributes for a give type to answer this question :

PS: I am developping an XL-Deploy plugin that allows the configuration of Custom Login Modules and Application Logins in the IBM WebSphere Wasx using the wsadmin commands chosen by the user on the "frontend" / synthetic.xml of the plugin
I attempted to print/return all the attributes :

But XL-Deploy keeps returning me an exception :
ScriptingException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException:
WASX7352E: Wrong number of arguments for "attributes" command.


If you have a config object instance and know the attribute name, you can show a specific attribute value with something like:  AdminConfig.showAttribute(configObj, "attrName").   You can find the attribute names for a given config type with AdminConfig.attributes(typeName)  (so you need one arg, the type name) .   That should help you to understand the examples e.g. here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=scripting-commands-adminconfig-object-using-wsadmin.    If that doesn't answer your question maybe include a code snippet showing more what you're trying to do.
